# Finding points of sudden large changes in stream gradient QGIS

Tags: qgis, slope, watershed

In QGIS I am trying to divide a streams shapefile at points at where there are sudden large increases or decreases in gradient.

[image]

For example at the red circle the gradient of the stream increases from about 3% to nearly 15%. I would like to split the stream feature at sudden changes like these.

I have gone through and done this by hand with many streams using the editor split features tool but this is slow. I am looking for a more efficient way to find these point and split the feature.